# Installation of Java Media Framework fails

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, installation, jmf

**I am failing to install JMF on my machine.**

My setup is:

- InteliJ-IDEA
- Ubuntu 16.4
- Java 8 (using open-jdk-amd64)

I have followed the instructions from oracle found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html). All they say is to execute `/bin/sh ./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin`. Which basically just runs the `.bin` file that they provide.

Nevertheless, during installation, I get the following error:

```
Unpacking...
tail: cannot open '+309' for reading: No such file or directory
Extracting...
./install.sfx.23041: 1: ./install.sfx.23041: cannot open ==: No such file
./install.sfx.23041: 1: ./install.sfx.23041: ==: not found
./install.sfx.23041: 3: ./install.sfx.23041: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
chmod: cannot access 'JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmstudio': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfregistry': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfinit': No such file or directory
./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin: 305: ./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin: JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfinit: not found
/bin/cp: cannot stat 'JMF-2.1.1e/lib/jmf.properties': No such file or directory
Done.
```

It seems that the error is related to directories not existing, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is that the performance pack or just the standard or 'core' JMF?

Comment: @AndrewThompson it's just the 'core' JMF. Should I download the full performance pack instead?

Comment: *"Should I download the full performance pack instead?"* **No!** The point of my asking is that if the app. only needs the core JMF, it can be used as easily as putting `jmf.jar` on the runtime class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line of that .bin file:

```
tail +309 $0 > $outname
```

It seems it's missing `-n` option, as it's needed to get last 309 lines of output, you'll need to change it to:

```
tail -n +309 $0 > $outname
```

To do that you can edit it with vim providing -b (for binary) option:

```
vim -b jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin
```

Source: [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/104511/comments/7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/104511/comments/7)

Answer (score 1):

I just did it done.This is the steps:

1. chmod +x jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin, if you don't chmod, you will get error:

   ```
      Unpacking...
      tail: cannot open `+309' for reading: No such file or directory
      Extracting...
      ./install.sfx.3639: line 1: ==: No such file or directory
      ./install.sfx.3639: line 3: syntax error neUQU599ù;···ÿrþÑÑÑ¢_Âò«KK)C{<>úú<<¿è
      QQRLÙÜÌLÅ^sfx.36 88ø$èåõÕ®¢¬,àöè´iÑ*ÒÒÒV~ámn.à7w^ÝÂÆ,;M¢`ÞòA$D¨®¨¨ @ ÉºÎwA'
   ```
2. Insert -n into the line "tail +309 $0 > $outname" in jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin. The steps to do it, enter commands:

   vim jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin

   type: /tail, press Enter to get the line,
   insert "-n" to get: tail -n +309 $0 > $outname.
3. change jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin to jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.zip
4. run unzip command to create folder JMF-2.1.1e and sub directories:

   unzip jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.zip .

   This is a funny step. But if you don't do it you get error:

   Unpacking...
    tail: cannot open `+309' for reading: No such file or directory
    Extracting...
    ./install.sfx.6017: 1: cannot open ==: No such file
    ./install.sfx.6017: 1: ==: not found
    ./install.sfx.6017: 3: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    chmod: cannot access`JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmstudio': No such file or directory
    chmod: cannot access `JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfregistry': No such file or directory
    chmod: cannot access`JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfinit': No such file or directory
    ./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin: 305: JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfinit: not found
    /bin/cp: cannot stat `JMF-2.1.1e/lib/jmf.properties': No such file or directory
5. Change zip back:

   mv jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.zip jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin,
6. Execute bin

   ./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin